# How to have 2 sidebar in beamer (Hannover theme)

Tags: beamer, sidebar

Using Hannover theme in beamer, I would like to have :

- one side bar for the titleframe,
- one siderbar for all the other frames,

so I tried the following MWE

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usetheme[width=.250\paperwidth]{Hannover}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{mysidebar-title}}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{mysidebar-generic}}
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=white}
\title[Title]{Title of the presentation (which may run over more than one line)}
\date[]{Very soon,\\ somewhere}
\author[]{Me and my colleagues}%
\institute{\centering Nice Lab logo }
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Short slide title}
First slide
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Very very veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooooooooooooooooooong title}
Last slide
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with for the titleframe sidebar (mysidebar-title)

```
\documentclass[border = 0.0cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle (7,21.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and for the other frames sidebar (mysidebar-generic)

```
\documentclass[border = 0.0cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=cyan!50!white] (0,0) rectangle (7,21.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got this idea of using {sidebar} and {sidebar left} from Beamer's user guide, but obviously there is something I didn't understand since it doesn't work and I get the same slidebar on all slides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}

\usetheme[width=.2\paperwidth]{Hannover}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=.2\paperwidth]{example-image-a}} 


\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=.2\paperwidth]{example-image-b}} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Short slide title}
First slide
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Very very very very loooooong slide title}
Second slide
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Very very veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy   looooooooooooooooooooooong title}
Last slide
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```